# ternary plot gridding using ternplot

Tags: matlab, ternplot

How to change the triangular grid to dotted lines in [ternplot](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/2299-alchemyst-ternplot)?  The default is solid lines. All options I have tried produces errors or unwanted effects.

Answer (score 1):

ok, got it..
add the following in plot for line 80 , 82 and 84 in ternaxes.m.

```
'linestyle',':'
```

this does the job

e.g. for the first

```
plot([lxa(i+1) lxb(nlabels - i + 2)], [lya(i+1) lyb(nlabels - i + 2)], ls, 'color', tc, 'linestyle',':', 'linewidth',1,...
           'handlevisibility','off');
```